# How to pass an object to a view controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, object, uiviewcontroller

How do you pass an object to a view controller, right before you push the view to show it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a property in the view controller, `synthesize` it, then assign `viewController.propertyName = someObject;`. Simple as  a dimple.

Comment: Not when trying to add a modal view controller...there's actually no way of setting the properties!